# How do I invoke --stream in the middle of a jq query?

Tags: stream, jq

I have a file of newline-separated JSON lists, the total of which I would like to count. I can do this with two invocations of jq as such:

```
cat file.nsj | jq -s ".[] | length" | jq -s "add"
```

But I would prefer to do it in a single jq invocation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is just to count the number of objects in the file full of lists, you could do this:

```
$ jq -n 'reduce inputs as $i (0; . + ($i | length))' file.nsj
```

Comment: It should be noted that streaming is not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado)'s solution which uses `-n`, **inputs** and **length** and **add**.

```
jq -n '[ inputs | length ] | add'  file.nsj
```